# Getting empty file as a attachment when using sendmail script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, sendmail

I would like to send an email along with the attachment using `sendmail` option with script.

I have received a mail successfully and got empty attachment.

Here, I am trying to attach a file called `test.txt` and **both the script and test.txt are present in the same location.**

Am I missing anything here?

Below is the script I used for testing the mail functionality.

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t << EOT
To:abc@gmail.com
Subject: Test
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="ABC"
--ABC
Content-Type:text/plain
Content-Disposition:inline

Hello, sendmail Test!!!!
--ABC
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment ; filename="test.txt"

--ABC--
EOT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have not put the content of the attachment. Please try the code below:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t << EOT
To:abc@gmail.com
Subject: Test
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="ABC"
--ABC
Content-Type:text/plain
Content-Disposition:inline

Hello, sendmail Test!!!!
--ABC
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode
Content-Disposition: attachment ; filename="test.txt"
`uuencode test.txt test.txt`
EOT
```

Comment: can you do `whereis uuencode`. If it is not installed, you can install it

Comment: Is there any other options available other than the uuencode command like something in build command

Comment: You can use other mail programs like `mailx` or `mutt` which have an option to attach files and does not require you to encode the files.